# How to follow up a 3-way interaction with one continuous variable in F-test fixed effects in mixed model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, interaction

In the Estimates of Fixed Effects SPSS-table, I don't understand why certain parameters are set to zero an just a dotted line appears (because they are redundant according to SPSS). Moreover, I don't get what the t-tests in this table mean. What is being tested here?

Parameter   Estimate    Std. Error  df  t   Sig.    95% Confidence Interval

[treatment=,00] * [stimuluscode=-1,00] * QuestionnaireScore ,371900 ,133225 1462,000    2,792   ,005    ,110567 ,633233

[treatment=,00] * [stimuluscode=,00] * QuestionnaireScore   ,379735 ,133225 1462,000    2,850   ,004    ,118402 ,641068

[treatment=,00] * [stimuluscode=1,00] * QuestionnaireScore  0b  0   .   .   .   .   .

[treatment=1,00] * [stimuluscode=-1,00] * QuestionnaireScore    0b  0   .   .   .   .   .

[treatment=1,00] * [stimuluscode=,00] * QuestionnaireScore  0b  0   .   .   .   .   .

[treatment=1,00] * [stimuluscode=1,00] * QuestionnaireScore 0b  0   .   .   .   .   .

a. Dependent Variable: inclusion.
b. This parameter is set to zero because it is redundant.

Any help or comments are very much appreciated!

best wishes,
Mariska

Answer (score 1):

The way I investigate 3 way interactions is to condition on one of the variables and then create 2-way interaction plots for the other 2 variables.  Creating 2-way interaction plots with continuous variables is a bit trickier but can be done.    I'm not sure how this is done in SPSS however.

Comment: Thank you Glen, this is very helpful. I plotted the 2-way interaction per group which makes it very clear. To test the significance, do you think I should simply run the analysis again in each group separately? And than, if significant in one group, investigate the 2-way interaction between the questionnaire score and the stimulus condition further per stimulus condition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you found the the 3 way interaction to be significant and now are trying to interpret what it means.  I don't think any more significance testing needs to be done.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? A reference that says that if I find the 3-way interaction, and I create 2-way interaction plots, that no further testing is required? By the way, I found the SPSS code for generalized: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40932/plotting-3-way-interaction-with-continuous-and-categorical-variables-in-linear-m?noredirect=1